# Why my network returns an integer larger than the output space length

Tags: python-3.x, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am learning Deep-Q-Network and have tried changing the code at https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/dqn.py to try out atari breakout.
But the output of my network is sometimes larger than the output space.
There was no problem with the original author's code, but after changing the code, there was a problem.

I'm running python 3.7 on Windows 10 using Numpy, keras-gpu, and running on AMD Ryzen 3700x and rtx 2070 super.
I thought it was a neural network model problem, but I can't do anything because I didn't know how to solve it.

```
class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
        self.gamma = 0.95    # discount rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.model = self._build_model()

    def _build_model(self):
        # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape=(105, 80, 1), 
activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse',
                      optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        state = np.expand_dims(state, 3)
        state = np.expand_dims(state, 0)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                next_state = np.expand_dims(next_state, 3)
                next_state = np.expand_dims(next_state, 0)
                state = np.expand_dims(state, 3)
                state = np.expand_dims(state, 0)
                target = (reward + self.gamma *
                      np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

Expect output 0 ~ 3 of act() but sometimes act() returns more than 2000.

Answer (score 0):

The output size of your neural network is dependent from the...

self.action_space = action_space

...line in **init**(...). What are you passing into the second argument when initializing the Agent? This is what you are setting as the output size of the neural network.

Comment: second argument of init() is 4. I don't know why this is wrong.

Comment: No, it's right then. That's the only issue I could thought of in this code. Maybe if you show more of the code we can work it out.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Sorry!